# I want to buy something, but don't have enough money on me

Tags: vocabulary

Suppose for example I want to buy something, but don't have enough money on
me. If I want to come back later to get it and don't want it to be sold
before I come back, what do I say to them? Is there any way to say - "Can you
put this aside for me for a few hours till I get back?"

Comment: Nothing wrong with: "Please can you put this aside for me for a few hours till I get back?"

Comment: -1 You've answered your own question. What is it about the phrase you don't like? Please edit your question to include details of what is wrong with your initial phrase.

Comment: Well, I just had doubts about it is all. It's also good to know other ways of putting it.

Answer (score 4):

"*Hold* it for me"? -- putting something on *hold* is not acting on it for the time being. They may, however, insist on your paying a token amount to *book*/ *reserve*/ *block* it for you.

Answer (score 4):

Some (large) stores have [layaway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layaway) where you purchase the item in installments, and the store keeps the item until you have fully paid it off.

Comment: Also called "lay-by" or "lay buy"

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to ask "Can you reserve this for me"?. By reserving or booking it in advance you just need to pay a small or portion of the actual price so that the item is not sold to anyone else.

These are common in many countries(especially India) when it comes to buying houses etc

Comment: Should it not be "Can *you* reserve this (for me)?"?

Comment: That sounds much better. Thanks for pointing out.Updated my answer.